# My Reputation Seems Frozen?

Tags: support, reputation

In the past 24-ish hours I've gained 75 rep (or so says my responses) but my score hasn't changed from 768.

Anyone else experiencing something like this?

Is it because I've only been active on Meta for a while, not the actual rpg.stackexchange 'parent' site?

Comment: You do not gain rep from meta posts.  See the [FAQ](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: Ahhhh now I get it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reputation on meta.rpg.stackexchange is the same as your reputation on rpg.stackexchange.com. You neither gain nor lose rep from participating on meta.

Now with [citation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/new-per-site-metas/)!

> Reputation is always inherited from the parent site. You cannot gain or lose reputation* on the per-site meta. This also means that some reputation related functions like the rep graph and bounties are not enabled on the per-site meta.
>
> [...]
>
> .* however, there is one exception: extreme misbehavior on the meta site will affect your parent site reputation. And not in, shall we say, the “good” way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not all real time.  Rep totals, mod status, etc., sometimes there's up to 24 hours of lag for it to get all caught up.  I don't think there's a meta vs main cap (though one could certainly make an argument for there being one - I would strongly suggest that you be more active there and then worry about meta issues).

Comment: Sure enough approx 24 hours later I've got a rep catch-up happening... though it's happening in increments and still doesn't add up. Bah; just numbers.